# Can infinitives act as nouns, adverbs, and adjectives?

Tags: infinitives

I've seen from multiple sources that infinitives can act as an adjective, adverb, and a noun.
However, there are a few examples where I'm unnsure on why they would act like that.

In this example, "Why does the study of Augustine, Dante, or Aquinas help us to be free?

Is the infinitive acting like a noun or adverb?

Also this example, "It's just a really difficult thing for us to do."

One last example, "I went there to seek advice."

I'm just asking for an explanation on how the infinitives are acting, and why, because I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'd say ***to be free, to do, to seek advice*** are all effectively ["adverbs of purpose"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4bkBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT81&lpg=PT81&dq=%22adverb+of+purpose%22+infinitive&source=bl&ots=3it2_BN4iD&sig=ACfU3U0kvzmcAdKUm9Xtz0UjHwOIGNp1oA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj074TXgLbpAhVaQhUIHUpaAIEQ6AEwDXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22adverb%20of%20purpose%22%20infinitive&f=false), but what definitions / terminology are you working with?

Comment: In the first two, they're noun phrases. The infinitive clause _to be free_ is acting as a  direct object of _help_, and the infinitive clause _for us to do_ is acting as the Extraposed subject of _is just a difficult thing_. In the third it's a purpose infinitive, since you can substitute _in order to_ for _to_; purpose infinitives act as adverbs, like this one.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you for the response; it's very clear and consise. Can you just explain what an "extraposed subject" is?

Comment: Not again @Ken Bill. You just don't get it, do you? Your muddling up word class (part of speech) and function. In your examples, they are infinitival clauses, but they're not functioning (your 'acting') as nouns or any other part of speech.  In your first example the infinitival clause is functioning as **complement** of "help"; in the second, "for us to do" is functioning as **extraposed subject**, and in the third “to seek advice” is functioning as a purpose **adjunct**. Complement, subject and adjunct are functions but noun, adjective etc. are not, they are word classes (parts of speech).

Comment: The traditional functional analogies of subordinate clauses with the parts of speech is mistaken. The point is that clauses are not nouns or adjectives or any other word class. They typically function as subject, complement, modifier. I gave you in a previous post a full breakdown of all the kinds of clauses and their typical functions.

Comment: @BillJ I'm just asking how the infinitives are acting. Many sources, including dictionary.com (https://www.dictionary.com/e/whats-an-infinitive-or-infinitive-phrase/) say that infinitives act as nouns, adjectives, and adverbs. So that's why I am asking to clarify how they act because I am receiving conflicting information at the same time. Also, what's the difference between saying the first two are noun phrases, like John Lawler said, and saying they're acting as nouns? You say that saying they're acting as nouns, adjectives, and adverbs is bad.

Comment: Also, John Lawler said purpose infinitives act as adverbs. Is this some sort of deadly sin saying this, or is it okay? I don't find any sites that say it is bad to refer to clauses as parts of speech, so do you happen to know of any?

Comment: Can you answer that, @BillJ?